# SSL issue with Apache httpd reverse proxy scheme

Tags: apache, chef-infra, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

Apologies this question is a mix of Chef and Apache-httpd, but ultimately I believe it's an Apache-httpd configuration issue.
I have a Chef client/node happily hitting a Chef Server w/ SSL.

**Chef client/node - /etc/chef/client.rb**

```
chef_server_url  'https://chefserverhostname/organizations/myOrg'
ssl_verify_mode  :verify_peer
```

I'm trying to put a proxy in front of the Chef Server so I can re-point down the road if needed.  Apache-httpd is installed fine (on the same box as Chef Server), all firewall and iptables are consistent with my below configuration.

**Chef Server - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8443
<VirtualHost *:8443>
 ServerAdmin me@email
 ServerName  chefserverhostname
 ServerAlias CDS-PROXY
 ProxyPass / https://chefserverhostname:443/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://chefserverhostname:443/
 RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

I reconfigure the Chef client/node's `client.rb` to point to `https://chefserverhostname:8443/organizations/myOrg`, and hope to have the request pass through the proxy.  ChefServer/nginx is listening on 443 and I'm assuming that it's taking care of the SSL decrypt, and 8443 is just the 'pass-through'.  But when I fire up my Chef client/node I'm getting an SSL error message:

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: chefserverhostname - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTTPS but your vhost does not have any configuration to enable mod_ssl or another TLS option. As such, you should be using `http://hostname:8443` but this *very* not recommended.

Chef Server is an appliance at heart and this kind of extra proxy layer is possible but not how things are intended to operate. You should just use the default setup which already includes a fronting nginx proxy for Erchef and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd this recipe and configure properly apache ssl and additional modules.

To me is also not ok to drop SSL connection on chef server - base on your current setup.

Since you have nginx on your machine you can extend the configuration there to support reverse proxy. Later on if you remove chefserver/nginx from this machine and you want only to leave proxy, install new nginx and apply the same conf for proxy configuration.

I rather drop apache from your setup.